# Copy Shape cache as Bitmap source image

Tags: javascript, caching, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have an EaselJS `Shape` object that contains cached graphics instructions, which are really expensive. Every frame I draw more graphics into the cache using `myShape.updateCache("source-overlay");`, so they'll not need to be redrawn the next frame.

But I want to remove the oldest cached graphics after 1 second, so I thought about creating a `buffer` Bitmap object, copy the cache from `myShape` into `buffer`'s `image` property, clear `myShape` current cache and continue drawing new graphics to it, then after 1 second clear the buffer.

Hard to explain, I know, but simplifying things up:

```
var myShape = new createjs.Shape();
var buffer = new createjs.Bitmap();

myShape.cache(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
stage.addChild(myShape, buffer);

function tick () {
    myShape.graphics.s("#F00").lt(Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100);
    myShape.updateCache("source-overlay");
    myShape.graphics.clear();
}
setInterval(function(){
    buffer.alpha = 1;
    buffer.image = myShape.getCacheDataURL();
    myShape.updateCache();
    createjs.Tween.get(buffer).to({alpha: 0}, 1000);
},1000);
```

The problem is that `myShape`'s cache won't appear as `buffer`'s source image. Why?

Comment: The getCacheDataURL method returns a string. You would have to pass that as the src of a new Image, and then set that image as the source.

Comment: I've noticed that right after posting the question, but this method is too slow. Isn't there a better way of doing this? Maybe copying the shape cache into another object's cache by calling `clone`...

Comment: You could wrap the output bitmap in a container, and cache that, to maintain a second cache.

Comment: I didn't get it @Lanny, can you provide sample code? Using the bitmap approach is slow because `getCacheDataURL` is expensive, even when running it a single time each 10 seconds (because when it runs everything freezes for ~5 frames), and I need to run it every time I want to clear the old graphics from `myShape`. The only solution I can think of would be implementing a better way to copy caches across `DisplayObjects` on EaselJS.

Comment: This basically copies the cache. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/hzgueoah/ -- just draws the current cache into a new item in a container, which itself is cached.

Comment: A cache copy would be handy :) https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/701

Comment: That's what I was looking for. If you want, you can post your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution from Grant Skinner for cloning a cache:

```
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(shape.cacheCanvas)
bmp.cache(x,y,w,h);
var cache2 = bmp.cacheCanvas;
```

Discussion here: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/701#issuecomment-160349081